# Find the top seller

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the top seller here. I was trying to use the below but i dont think this is right. I can see other ids that have bigger totals plus i think i should be using a SUM function instead of MAX.

```
select selleruserid
from sales_fact
where price = (select max(price) from sales_fact)
```

[image: Tables]

Comment: hint `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: I was trying this: 

select selleruserid, sum(price)
from sales_fact
group by selleruserid

however, I need the total amount since there are a few rows that are using the same id.

Comment: I also tried the following but I get the same as the previous code. I am trying to get the id with the highest amount after the sum. 

select selleruserid, max(pricesum)
from (select sum(price) as pricesum, selleruserid
from sales_fact
group by selleruserid) group by selleruserid

Comment: now you have the grouped sum, try putting it in a subquery.

Comment: I came up with this: 

select selleruserid, sum(price) as total
from sales_fact
group by selleruserid
order by sum(price) desc

But i get a list instead of a single result. However, it does give me the highest amount with the id.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to get the total sales of each seller and choose the seller who has the most sales.

The seller who has the most sales:

```
SELECT max(totalPrice) as totalPrice,selleruserid
FROM (SELECT sum(price) AS totalPrice,selleruserid FROM sales_fact GROUP BY selleruserid)
```

Total sales of each seller:

```
SELECT totalPrice as totalPrice,selleruserid
FROM (SELECT sum(price) AS totalPrice,selleruserid FROM sales_fact GROUP BY selleruserid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FETCH` clause with `TIES` option as follows:

```
select selleruserid, sum(price) as total 
  from sales_fact 
 group by selleruserid 
 order by sum(price) desc
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

OR You can use the analytical function `RANK` as follows:

```
select selleruserid, total from
  (select selleruserid, sum(price) as total,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum(price) DESC) AS rn
    from sales_fact 
   group by selleruserid) t
 where rn = 1
```